# Send file in Ajax and input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

I've a form to upload a file and an input.

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="file" id="file">
</form>
```

This is what I'm using to send the file in Ajax:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data: form_data,                         
        url: 'upload.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        ...
```

But I dont get the input value.

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You would need another `append()` for the text input key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to pass the whole form element into `FormData()` than manually append to it when you need all the data from that form

Instead of:

```
var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
```

Just do:

```
var form_data = new FormData(this);// `this` is the form element submit event occured on
```

And add `name` attributes to the form controls:

```
<form id="form">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, and the I can get the file in PHP like this `$_FILES['file']['name']` or like this `$_POST['file']['name']` ?

Comment: No...`$_FILES['file']` and `$_POST['name']`